# Subtract waves from tilemap

Tags: shaders, waves

I'm wondering how I could create a shader that would turn a randomly generated shape like this:
[image]

And turn it into something more like this:
[image]

Essentially just creating a top down view of ocean waves that would flow in and out. I would prefer to be able to subtract this shape from a tilemap.

[image]

Any resources or pseudo code on how I could get started with this would be great.

Comment: [You might be interested in the domain warping technique described here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/89878/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory seems like a step in the right direction, I'll read into domain warping. Thank you